# Identification of old animated TV series ( Crashed spaceship, astronaut waiting to be rescued? diner?)

Tags: story-identification

I am searching for an old (at least 10 years ago) animated TV show.
It was kind of a comedy; a space astronaut crashed on a planet (maybe asteroid) where there is some kind of diner, and he is waiting to be rescued by the government or something like that.

Anyone know about this TV show?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SCIFI exchange! Can you remember the year? Any other details? And is it crashed or crushed?

Comment: Its crashed, It was at least 10 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would the show you're looking for be called [Captain Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Star)? They landed on the planet and are awaiting orders.

> The story of Captain Star involves the crew of the rocket ship Boiling Hell, who have been **ordered to a deserted planet** known only as "The Nameless Planet" at the Ragged Edge of the Universe. The ship's crew consists of the egocentric and often paranoid Captain Star, Dana Scully-esque science officer Scarlette, nine-headed engineer Jones, and fish-keeping Navigator Black. They are later joined by a robot, Jim-Bob-Bob, who performs laundry duty and various other servitudes.
>
> Captain Star is introduced in the opening theme as "the greatest hero any world has ever known". A legendary explorer who has hundreds of planets named after him, Captain Star's birthday is a holiday throughout the universe. Throughout the series, **the characters await further orders from Mission Control** which never come. It is unclear whether Mission Control has simply forgotten about Star and his crew, but the implication is that they have put the aging Star out to pasture, but spared him the indignity of forcing him to retire, and kept him on active duty so that he can continue to be a hero to the public. Events occurring on and off the planet, however, frequently require Star's intervention.

The diner was built by Navigator Black:

> Once the navigator of the Boiling Hell, Navigator Black **sets up a small fish-shaped restaurant** on The Nameless Planet and becomes the cook. Obsessed with fish, the restaurant is filled with aquariums.

Comment: Yes it is.. 
Amazing thank you!