# Animation - travelling crew: the captain, a red-headed woman and a man with eight arms and 8-9 heads

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a sci-fi cartoon tv show

The show is about a travelling crew: the captain, a red-headed woman and a man with eight arms and 8-9 heads.

Comment: [Captain Star?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Star) You'd have to add more detail though, otherwise the question might get closed.

Comment: Sorry, Gallifreian. I saw your comment after I posted an answer. :) If you want, I can yield.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  -  nah, it's okay :D I got satisfied when I found this on Google: I only had to search for `animation 8 arms 9 heads`

Comment: ^_^ Close to the same for me "cartoon space multiple heads"

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  -  it's a [dupe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36691/70236) though.

Comment: If this one gets accepted... I kind of wonder which episode the answer one answered for.

Comment: Ah. And looking at it again, they might have been confusing Navigator Black's restaurant for the diner.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  -  aaaand we have a dead OP. Love those on a story ID question.

Comment: Sadly common. They log in, post a question, then lose track of it. Or glance at it when not logged in, say "Oh, that's it", then never click the checkmark. :) **user76716, should you return, don't forget to click the checkmark to accept. Please? {puppy dog eyes}**

Answer (score 7):

This may be the 1997 British/Canadian animated series, [Captain Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Star).

> The story of Captain Star involves the crew of the rocket ship Boiling Hell, who have been ordered to a deserted planet known only as "The Nameless Planet" at the Ragged Edge of the Universe. The ship's crew consists of the egocentric and often paranoid Captain Star, Dana Scully-esque science officer Scarlette, nine-headed engineer Jones, and fish-keeping Navigator Black. They are later joined by a robot, Jim-Bob-Bob, who performs laundry duty and various other servitudes.
>
> Captain Star is introduced in the opening theme as "the greatest hero any world has ever known". A legendary explorer who has hundreds of planets named after him, Captain Star's birthday is a holiday throughout the universe. Throughout the series, the characters await further orders from Mission Control which never come. It is unclear whether Mission Control has simply forgotten about Star and his crew, but the implication is that they have put the aging Star out to pasture, but spared him the indignity of forcing him to retire, and kept him on active duty so that he can continue to be a hero to the public. Events occurring on and off the planet, however, frequently require Star's intervention.

Scarlette would be the redhead and Jones is the multi-headed and multi-armed man.

[image: Image of the crew]

Here is the first episode to see if it is the right one:

To further quote the Wikipedia article:

> Only thirteen episodes of thirty-minutes each were produced and aired. The series ran on the British ITV and Canadian Teletoon networks from 1997 to 1998. The show was also later repeated on Locomotion in Latin America, Nickelodeon UK in the United Kingdom, and Space in Canada.